# Method to pass 2 parameters to a PUT request in Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I am trying to update a single record in a table. The code is as follows:

```
public void UpdateStudent(int id, int studentClass)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

    myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "update Tbl_Students set Class="+ studentClass+" where Roll_Number=" + id + ";";

    sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

    myConnection.Open();

    int rowUpdated = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

How can I pass both the id and the Class to the URL in fiddler?

Comment: Are they part of the URL or part of the body?

Comment: ?! What are you talking about? This code connects to certain database; this database is hosted somewhere (fiddler, your computer or anywhere else); you have to make sure that the connection reaches the target destination (e.g., the firewall allows you to go through, the credentials are right, the table/columns names exist, etc.). If you have doubts about any specific issue, you would have to provide all the required information. With this code + the provided information it is impossible to know what is going on.

Comment: As part of the URL, I want to enter something like http://localhost:xxxx/api/Student/1,6 or something similar. Is it possible in Fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler, like any other commercial product (application, web or whatever), has certain rules which you have to follow. SO is for programming questions (i.e., problems which might be found in a code; not blind guesses regarding the restrictions which a given company might have set in its products). For questions regarding how to use a commercial product, you should better contact the given company/use its help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I was able to solve the problem by changing my code slightly.
The code is as follows:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("UpdateStudent")]
    public void UpdateStudent(int id, [FromBody]Tbl_Students student)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

        myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "update Tbl_Students set Class=" + student.Class + " where Roll_Number=" + id + ";";

        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

        myConnection.Open();

        int rowUpdated = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

In Fiddler, I pass the id as a part of the URL and the studentClass as a JSON in the Request Body. I also added the `Content-Type:application/json` which I had forgotten to before. I have added the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using WCF REST Service.
Implement following menthod and you can do what you want over fiddler:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "api/student/{id}/{studentclass}")]
[OperationContract]
void UpdateEmployee(int id, int studentclass);
```

Kindly refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd203052.aspx) for more detail on RESTFUL WCF Service.